# Define custom functions for Formula Parsing/Eval VIs (Mathematics > Scripts & Formulas)

Tags: labview

I need a numerical input, but I want the user to be able to input a formula and not just the value.

To do this, I am using a string control and the "Substitute Variables" and "Eval Formula String" VIs from Mathematics > Scripts & Formulas.

**Is there a way I can define custom functions that can be used in these formulas?**

[image: Front Panel]
[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: So you want to declare some sin5 function and then use it on in Formula?

Comment: Yes, I want declare a function and use it in the formula. (The sin function in the image is a built in and already works.)

Comment: The vis are open, I think you can search and add your one in the default list

Comment: Do you mean editing the formula parsing VI's?

Comment: yes, editing gpower VIs

Comment: I looked at the VIs and it would require changes in two VIs deep in the VI hierarchy. I am not sure if its a good idea to modify the VIs from NI as it would change the behavior for all Labview Applications on my System and would probably be overridden with the next update.

Comment: You can just save your entier tree as previous version, it will collect all used vis, libs and save as on the other place. Than change saved as versions and make your own lib for your use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enum and case structure for this -

[image]

Here is the block diagram and an example result

[image]

For me here I have enum options for 'Add', 'Multiply', 'Squared', 'Sine' and 'Cosine'

Comment: J-Dizzle: Take the VI that you wrote, select the contents of the block diagram and then choose "Edit >> Create VI Snippet From Selection". This creates a PNG file that you can post here, but it is a magic PNG -- if dragged onto a block diagram, it automatically becomes the code.

Comment: This is not what I mean. In my case the formula is the input parameter and I want to declare a function that can be used in that formula.

Comment: megle - please clarify your vocabulary, it is confusing and I can't parse. I think you mean "J-Dizzle your code is not what I meant. For my Case Structure the Selector input is a string form of the formula. I would like them to be able to pick the formula type, and then ALSO type in it's details", is this correct??? Also to note, 'formula' and 'function' are loose and ambiguous here - please clarify what they are... ;0

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum flexibility I think you should consider [Math Scripts Nodes](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3256/en/). You'll be able to generate run-time your .m file and call it to be executed also including [user-defined functions](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/373123C-01/lvtextmathmain/calling_udf/).

An other option is described [here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/A-dynamic-formula-node-in-a-LabVIEW-execution-file/td-p/885390), making use of Phyton. It's very interesting and allow you to define all the custom functions you need.

In the same thread you'll find a trick to use also a [Formula Node](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/glang/formula_node/) to execute a formula defined at run time, but I would avoid it (and I can't guarantee it works).